# AWS: Configuring Domain for RESTful App (Client and Server)

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, dns, cross-domain

I have a RESTful application.  The client is AngularJS built on Node.JS, and the server is Grails.  I would like to run them on AWS Elastic beanstalk under the same domain so that I don't have cross-domain problems, for example `mydomain.com\myapp-api` and `mydomain.com\myapp-view`.

I've already configured Grails applications on AWS with Elastic beanstalk and Route 53 in the past, so I know how that works.

Answer (score 0):

That is not supported by the preconfigured platforms on Beanstalk, but it is possible to implement using Docker containers. At every release, you would have to deploy a new docker image with both apps.

You can also have separate environments on Beanstalk, or even use S3 for the view, and use AWS CloudFront to distribute content. Using Cloudfront behaviors, you can send static requests to one origin and api calls to another.